# How to wrap a fields or other elements in div block?

Tags: 7, theming

I want to wrap these elements in one div (this div should be before div class = row) but I don't know where to add this div

[image]

Example:

```
<div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
            <div class = "my_custom> 
             <div class="views-field views-field-title">
             <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
             <div class="views-field views-field-field-product-reference">
             <div class="views-field views-field-commerce-price">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am using Bootstrap theme and views_bootstrap module.

Comment: I use drupal 7 version

Comment: Are you using the [Views Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) module?

Comment: yes I use this module and I use bootstrap sub-theme as well

Comment: The div you want to add before row, where does it end? does it wrap the entire view? or just the row?

Comment: it will wrap all row

Comment: also I want to add div to every div after row

Comment: It is easier for us if you can provide the HTML code of the structure which you expect to have.

Comment: You can use field rewrite option in views to group all fields in a div.

Steps: 1. Check exclude from display for each field. 2. Add custom text field at the end. Enter token in rewrite option of this field.You can use html too.

i.e. you have two fields in view title and body then you to put below in rewrite textbox.

<div class="css-class">[title][body]</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a template for your view fields:

**views-view-fields--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbNIb.jpg).tpl.php**

```
Example: views-view-fields--hello-world--block-1.tpl.php
```

In template file you add code like this, this is just an example, modify as you need:

```
<div class="example"> 
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
     <div class="my_custom"> 
       <?php echo $fields["title"]->content . 
                  $fields["body"]->content . 
                  $fields["field_product_reference"]->content .
                  $fields["commerce_price"]->content; 
       ?>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Place your template file in `/sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/templates` folder and **clear/flush cache to see changes**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42877/discussion-on-answer-by-no-sssweat-how-to-wrap-a-fields-or-other-elements-in-div).

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a simpler answer with no coding needed just use [Views Fieldset](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fieldsets).
So install the module, add your row class on the view (Format > Settings > Row Class).

Then add a fieldset (Fields > Add > Global: Fieldset), in the settings of the fieldset choose div and to the HTML classes add the column classes. Don't forget to to go to Fields > Rearrange and put your fields in the fieldset group.

That's it.